# Typescript Exclude<> behaves differently in 3.8 and previous compared to newer versions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript3.8

I noticed a difference when using Exclude in Typescript in version 3.8 and previous compared to newer versions.

Consider the following example:

```
interface Layer {
    id: string;
}

export enum LayerType {
    Text,
    Image,
}

interface ImageLayer extends Layer {
    src: string,
    layerType: LayerType.Image;
}
interface TextLayer extends Layer {
    text: string,
    layerType: LayerType.Text;
}

type Layercombined = ImageLayer & TextLayer;
type IgnoredProperties = "layerType";

type WithoutLayerType = {
    [key in Exclude<keyof Layercombined, IgnoredProperties>]: string;
};
const test: WithoutLayerType = {
    id: "17",
    src: "test",
    text: "test",
    layerType: "type",
};
```

The assignment of the object to `const test` would fail up until 3.8 and IMO rightfully complain that layerType does not exist on `WithoutLayerType` since it was excluded. In 3.9 and newer versions the assignment is fine though.
It feels like a bug to me, but I'm sure that there is something to this that I do not understand :)
Maybe someone can enlighten me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue arises because how TypeScript changed it's handling of the type checking on [intersection and optional properties in 3.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#stricter-checks-on-intersections-and-optional-properties).

Prior to 3.9, the type result of *LayeredCombined* would be the combination of all properties.  On and after 3.9, the result is never, because of the conflict between the types for *layerType* (one is *LayerType.Image*, the other is *LayerType.Text*).

Because *LayeredCombined* is now the type *never*, the type of the string literal from *keyof Layercombined* doesn't contain any properties from ImageLayer or TextLayer and therefore nothing can be excluded.

The easiest work around is redefining *Layercombined* as the following:

```
type Layercombined = Partial<ImageLayer> & Partial<TextLayer>;
```

This will get you all the keys because now layerType will have one possible value, *undefined*.